# Add XML element to existing XmlNodeList C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting strucked in below concept.

I have an xml string like this...

```
<ResponseData> 
  <a> 
    <a1>1</a1> 
    <a2>1</a2> 
  </a> 
  <b> 
    <b1>1</b1> 
    <b2>2</b2> 
  </b> 
  <b> 
    <b1>3</b1> 
    <b2>4</b2> 
  </b> 
  <c> 
    <c1>1</c1> 
    <c2>2</c2> 
  </c> 
</ResponseData>
```

and desired output for XML string is

```
<ResponseData> 
  <a> 
    <a1>1</a1> 
    <a2>1</a2> 
  </a> 
  <B>
    <b> 
      <b1>1</b1> 
      <b2>2</b2> 
    </b> 
    <b> 
      <b1>3</b1> 
      <b2>4</b2> 
    </b> 
  </B>
  <c> 
    <c1>1</c1> 
    <c2>2</c2> 
  </c> 
</ResponseData>
```

How to add `<B></B>` attribute for whole `<b></b>` elements?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried || investigated?

Comment: Also note that `B` isn't an attribute - you're asking to create another *element*, and nest existing elements within it. I strongly advise you to look into LINQ to XML.

Comment: This documentation i've made will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1528/xmldocument-and-the-system-xml-namespace#t=201704031509099728241

Comment: This is a really confusing question, has the XML been serialised from an object? where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating this xml?  Could you simply use string functions to find and insert the corresponding container tags before the first "`<b`>" and after the last "`</b`>"?

Comment: I converted dataset in to xml and got this result.  I cannot simply insert <B> tag before <b> and after </b>, because you have seen <b> & </b> are multiple..

Comment: And I have tired until this part and could not found a solution how to add new element to existing XMLNodeList. .........XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<ResponseData><a><a1>1</a1><a2>1</a2></a><b><b1>1</b1><b2>2</b2></b><b><b1>3</b1><b2>4</b2></b><c><c1>1</c1><c2>2</c2></c></ResponseData>");

            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

            //Create a new node.
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("B");

            XmlNodeList accountNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("b");

Comment: By the sounds of things its not the XML you should be changing its the dataset. You need to rearrange it to fit the output you want.